# BlurEffect has a long delay before the effect is applied

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, blur

I am trying to use a popup window on another window. The popup is called using the showDialog method, where the popup itself is just another window designed as a popup.

I want to make the rear window blured, in order to set focus to the popup.
I tried using:

```
 BlurEffect objBlur = new BlurEffect();
 objBlur.Radius = 30;
 this.Effect = objBlur;
 popup.showDialog();
 this.Effefct = null;
```

The problem is that the program kinda get "stuck" for a while, it takes too long for the popup to be seen.

Without the blur effect the popup of course shows instantly. When the Radius is lower the delay time is lower, but evern with a very low Radius as 5 it takes too much time.

What is the problem? can I solve this? if not is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change [BlurEffect.KernelType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.blureffect.kerneltype.aspx) to [Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.kerneltype.aspx) value. A Gaussian kernel creates a higher-quality blur but if performance is a concern, use the Box kernel because it uses less calculations. Also be sure that [RenderingBias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.blureffect.renderingbias.aspx) is Performance (as default).